# Why retain count is bigger, than I expect (using addSubview)

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

Why counter variable equals 3, not 2?

```
@interface ScoreView : UIImageView
...


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame 
{   
    if (!(self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) 
        return self;

    _scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 10)];
    [self addSubview:_scoreLabel];

    int counter = [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] retainCount]; // WHY 3?
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the docs on retainCount? "... it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method"

Comment: I have read docs for "beginners". It says retain counter increases, when "alloc/copy/new" take place and decrease, when release called.
If you have specific docs - please share with me a link to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`-retainCount` is not reliable](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount).

> **Important:** This method is typically of no value in debugging memory management issues. Because any number of framework objects may have retained an object in order to hold references to it, while at the same time autorelease pools may be holding any number of deferred releases on an object, it is very unlikely that you can get useful information from this method.

In your case, the particular reason is because `-subview` also causes all subviews to be retained once, by *copying* the value of `.layer.sublayers` to a new array*:

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 10)];
NSLog(@"%d", [label retainCount]);  // 1
[someView addSubview:label];
NSLog(@"%d", [label retainCount]);  // 2
[someView subviews];
NSLog(@"%d", [label retainCount]);  // 3
```

There is no need to worry about it, as the array is autoreleased and the retainCount will drop back to 2 later. All you need is to ensure is the net retain count cause by the current function is consistent with the ownership status.

---

*: The particular implementation of `.subviews` is:

```
-(NSArray*)subviews {
            // irrelevant ... snipped

        NSArray* sublayers = [_layer.sublayers copy];
        int count = [sublayers count];

            // irrelevant ... snipped

            res = CFArrayCreateMutable(NULL, count, &kCFTypeArrayCallBacks);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; ++ i) {
                UIView* view = _UIView([sublayers objectAtIndex:i]);
                if (view)
                    CFArrayAppendValue(res, view);
                    // ^-- this causes an extra -retain to each subview.
            }

            // irrelevant ... snipped
 }
```

Comment: Whoah, is that reverse-engineered Apple copyrighted code there?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure closing braces ']' on sending message-

```
  _scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 10)];//here
  [self addSubview:_scoreLabel];

  int counter = [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] retainCount]; //here
```

now check and let us know for further problem.

Comment: I'm sorry to post not correct version of code.
I have edited first message with correct one.
And I still have counter equals 3, not 2

Answer (score 0):

I think that U don't know about the retain mechanism.

It's very simple.

initializer [init] and [copy] methods should increase retainCount. ==> retainCount == 1
after calling [addSubview], self has new retain of _scoreLabel, then retainCount + 1 ==> retainCount == 2

so, U got the retainCount(2)

U should change your code with the following.

_scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 10);

==> _scoreLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 10, 10)] autorelease];

or show call release like this

==> [_scoreLabel release];

[autorelease] methods would release the instance when event driving complete.
You must call [autorelease] or [release] after initialize a instance with call [init] or [copy].

Comment: I release _scoreLabel in dealloc method.
You wrote, that I have got retainCount(2) - but WHY retain count is 3?

int counter = [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] retainCount]; //here

Comment: haha self subviews would make new array of subviews.
the subviews is not self internal container, It's copy of internal container.
- following doucments.
- @property(nonatomic, readonly, copy) NSArray *subviews

so call [subviews] then new array(autoreleased NSArray).
U got the retainCount(3).